# SQL Server 2008 integrated security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Anybody please tell, from where I can download sqljdbc_auth.dll for a 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking the `installation directory\sqljdbc_version\language\auth\` directory of the machine for the file? As directed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The dll is "sqljdbc_auth.dll" which is included in MS SQL JDBC driver archive [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505) press Download, download Eula, then finally download the jdbc driver archive and look for dll inside